# DynamoDb Item's data are missing from the Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have been using aws dynamodb to store the user details (like mail Id, username, etc...) and before it was fine. until today, suddenly few row's data disappeared from the table and the data was empty can't able to figure out why this is happening. we didn't even changed anything and user also not aware of this. is anyone faced this kind of issue before? Kindly give me any suggestion to figure this out.

[image: screenshot from dynamodb]

Comment: Click on the item to see all the data, the ui shows arbitrary rows. The data itself cannot disappear without you (or someone else) performing the corresponding put / update operation.

Comment: yes I already did that, it also doesn't contain the data which it previously has.
now, its just id only and it was not for one row, three rows are having the same issue
and is there any way to monitor the previous operation done on the table

Comment: Are the rows which are missing data are some old(er) data instances?

Comment: It was not old instance, even the row which was created before that row are existing but only three rows data are missing, is that happened to anyone before? because it was old instances?

Comment: If you haven't already,  you should enable CloudTrail Logs and you should enable DynamoDB PITR. See [Logging DynamoDB Operations by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html). Also, see [Restoring a DynamoDB Table to a Point in Time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/PointInTimeRecovery.Tutorial.html).